# Laws of indicies

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi I'm really confused on how to solve this problem.
$$
(p\sqrt p)^2
$$
I know the square root of $x$ up is to a power of a half...

Comment: I edited your expression to make it readable. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $p\sqrt p = p^1p^{1/2} = p^{1+(1/2)} = p^{3/2}$.

$$(p\sqrt p)^2 = (p^{3/2})^2 = p^3$$

First, I have used the property that tells us $a^ba^c = a^{b+c}.$

Secondly, I used the property that tells us $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}.$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\left( p\sqrt{p}\right)^2 = p\sqrt{p}p\sqrt{p} = pp\sqrt{p}\sqrt{p} = p^2 p = p^3$$

Answer (score 0):

If we take the power inside and expand we get:

$$(p\sqrt p)^2 = (p^2)(\sqrt p)^2 = (p^2)(p) = p^3$$